# Siri Intent Suggested Invocation Phrase not displaying in ShortcutViewController

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to enable a simple Siri Intent for my iOS app, with a TableView cell functioning to invoke `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`, with the TableView as its delegate. However, the suggested invocation phrase that is supposed to display on the controller view, does not.

I'm extremely new to Swift, and so I haven't tried much else as I do not know what to try

The invoking function is:

```swift
getSiriView() {
 intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Get a joke"

 let siriView = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: INShortcut(intent: intent)!)

 siriView.delegate = self;
 self.present(siriView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and its delegate extensions are as follows:

```swift
//
//  ViewControllerSiriExtensions.swift
//  Helium
//
//  Created by Richard Robinson on 2019-04-26.
//  Copyright © 2019 Richard Robinson. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import IntentsUI

extension TableViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButtonDelegate {
    func present(_ addVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(addVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func present(_ editVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(editVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}

extension TableViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {
    public func addVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, didFinishWith voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func addVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension TableViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {
    public func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, didUpdate voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, didDeleteVoiceShortcutWithIdentifier deletedVoiceShortcutIdentifier: UUID) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func editVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension TableViewController {
    public var intent: JokeIntent {
        return JokeIntent()
    }
}
```

Currently, the controller appears and works properly, except it does not display the suggested phrase.

Comment: did you solve it ?